# VirtualBox CentOS VM - Can't Get Mouse To Work On Install

Tags: virtualbox

I have VirtualBox with two VMs.  One is a fully installed Debian VM, which is working fine with guest editions. The other is a new VM I created to install CentOS.  The problem is, when I launch the new VM I can't use the mouse on the install screens of CentOS.  It gives the error on VirtualBox of **"The virtual machine reports that the guest OS does not support mouse pointer integration in the current video mode"**.  Everyone is saying on Google that you need guest editions on the host.  I can confirm I already have this installed that, because it's working with my Debian machine, and my package manager on my host machine shows it's installed (as shown below):

```
$  pacman -Q virtualbox-guest-iso 
virtualbox-guest-iso 6.0.4-1
```

I also tried all of the different video modes (VMSVGA, VBoxVGA, VBoxSVGA) with no success.  What's strange is that I seem to be able to click/move my physical mouse around within the VM and select things, I just don't have a cursor.  So how can I solve this issue?  I need my mouse working on the CentOS installation screens, that is all I want.

EDIT: I have tried installing a number of different ISO's on this new VM, inclusive of Debian, RedHat, Fedora, and CentOS.  I only seem to have this issue specifically when trying to install CentOS and RedHat.

Answer (score 6):

Same happened to me. Eventually I found a solution on the internet that worked for me: In the machine setting on the System menu, set the pointing device to USB tablet instead of the default PS/2 Mouse.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me very well.

Answer (score 1):

Worked that in the machine setting on the System menu, set the pointing device to USB tablet instead of the default PS/2 Mouse.